# SQL select all rows containing a value in other column

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I want to select all "A-No" rows related to "Tokyo". The table and the desired outcome is at the picture. If a row contains Tokyo, then i need to list all related "No" rows. I have two "Tokyo" value but i need to list 6 rows according to the "A-No" column.

Picture: https://ibb.co/cOFBHx

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOc3a.jpg)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider adding what you've tried so far, so that other people can help you to improve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a_no in (select t2.a_no from t t2 where t2.b_city = 'Tokyo');
```